# Instagram Basic API Unable to get access token for redirect url with parameters

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to use ( for some time now) the Instagram Basic API , however I am stuck at the point of getting the access token using https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token .The problem seems to be with the redirect uri having params .

The redirect URI that is not working is: https://localhost/clean1/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=ipl-options which gives me an error :

> Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri
> is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

This is  the screenshot of the request using POSTMAN  below :

[image]

This is the OAuth Redirect URI in dev. console in Facebook .

[image]

I tried a simple redirect URI like https://localhost/clean1/wp-admin/options-general.php which seems to be working :

[image]

I'd double checked and compared both and there doesnt seem to be any other difference other than the redirect uri . Does anybody have any idea what may be wrong  and how to get it to work for the uri with paramater?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody finds this usefull I found out the problem was with redirect URI not being encoded . In POSTMAN you can right click on the redirect uri value and choose Encode URI component .